# Syntax error when trying to pass a value from one variable to another

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a root finder using secant method. I just did the same thing with Newton Raphson method, and have not been getting this error. It comes when I say xold=xnow when trying to reassign the values for each iteration. It doesn't give me any information other than 'syntax error', and I used this exact method for Newton's with no issues. What gives?

```
def secant(n):
    def function(x):
        f=x-math.cos(x)
    return f

    xold=0.0
    xnow=1.0

    for i in range(n):
        xnew=xnow-function(xnow)((xnow-xold)/(function(xnow)-function(xold))
        xold=xnow
        xnow=xnew
    return xnew

def main():
    print("The root is",secant(10))

return
```

Comment: VTC as typo; first count your parentheses to solve the immediate problem. Then remember that Python requires an explicit `*` for multiplication to address the next one.  Aside: in the future, please post the entire error trace --  _show_ your error, don't just describe it.

Comment: The function you post would never reach the line `xold=xnew`; you would get a `NameError` at the line `return f`, assuming `f` is not also a global variable. Fix your indentation.